# Can side effects be avoided with ES2015 Iterators and the Iteration Protocols?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, iterator, ecmascript-6, side-effects

As a functional programmer I want to keep my main code free from side effects and shift them to the edge of the application. ES2015 `Iterator`s and the `Iteration Protocols` are a promising way to abstract specific collections. However, `Iterator`s are also stateful. Can I still avoid side effects if I rely on immutable `Iterable`s exclusively?

Comment: If the iterable is immutable, what side effects could the iterator possibly have?

Comment: It is still multicast that is, you can share the `next` effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Iterator`s cause observable mutations

Iterators have one essential property: They decouple the consumer from the producer of the `Iterable` by serving as an intermediary. From the consumer point of view the data source is abstracted. It might be an `Array`, an `Object` or a `Map`. This is totally opaque to the consumer. Now that the control of the iteration process is moved from the producer to the `Iterator`, the latter can establish a pull mechanism, which can be lazily used by the consumer.

To manage its task an `Iterator` must keep track of the iteration state. Hence, it needs to be stateful. This is per se not harmful. However, it gets harmful as soon as state changes are observable:

```js
const xs = [1,2,3,4,5];

const foo = itor => Array.from(itor);

const itor = xs.keys();

console.log(itor.next()); // 0

// share the iterator

console.log(foo(itor)); // [2,3,4,5] => observed mutation

console.log(itor.next()) // {value: undefined, done: true} => observed mutation
```

These effects occur even if you only work with immutable data types.

As a functional programmer you should avoid `Iterator`s or at least use them with great care.

Comment: Great question, with a great answer. Also, what's a thunk?

Comment: "*Iterators seem to encourage people to mutate iterables*" - I don't see that. The spec just requires them not to break in case they are mutated during iteration, but it stays a bad practice.

Comment: Yes, one should never share iterators. One should share the iterable - being able to create a new (local, own) iterator by calling `[Symbol.iterator]()` is the whole point of the iteration protocol.

Comment: @Bergi People will use the iteration protocol as they see fit. I think a good language feature should be inherently safe - not only if you obey specific rules.

Comment: @Bergi _"The spec just requires them not to break"_ - that's what I mean with "encourage".

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry for the delay: A [thunk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19862784/6445533) is a nullary function (without arguments), whose only purpose is to lazily evaluate its containing computation.

Comment: @ftor you'll never be able to save people that just don't know any better. `while(true)` can put your program in an infinite loop – sometimes intended, sometimes not – either way, there's some risk there, but I don't think languages should be trying to prevent people from using such expressions. Mutations are only naïvely seen as "always bad" – invoking the iterator and localizing mutations is perfectly acceptable/appropriate use of the interface; and it does not preclude you from writing function, side-effect-free programs.

Comment: @naomik: `ref.next()` is a state change and this behavior is pretty implicit in my opinion. This post is maybe a bit provocative in tone but only to make a point. I spent a lot of time with that protocol only to finally realize that I can obtain a similar behavior by using pure functions, recursion and thunks but without the drawbacks.

Comment: @naomik Working with the iteration protocol simply increases the potential and the risk of side effects. You need a greater portion of confidence in the code. Risk and benefit of a language constructs must be balanced. I think iterators do not meet this requirement.

Comment: @ftor is it too late to say I've totally reversed my stance re: stateless iterators since my last comment? I had totally forgot about this question until I was working on something similar just recently (as you saw) ^_^

Comment: @naomik of course not, I do that all the time. There is a pattern that I've recognized though: Eventually I achieve it with some sort of function, mostly combinators, mostly pure.

Answer (score 1):

A pure iterator is dead simple. All we need is

- the current value
- a closure that advances the iterator
- a way to signal that the iterator is exhausted
- an appropriate data structure containing these properties

```js
const ArrayIterator = xs => {
  const aux = i => i in xs
    ? {value: xs[i], next: () => aux(i + 1), done: false}
    : {done: true};

  return aux(0);
};

const take = n => ix => {
  const aux = ({value, next, done}, acc) =>
    done ? acc
      : acc.length === n ? acc
      : aux(next(), acc.concat(value));

  return aux(ix, []);
};

const ix = ArrayIterator([1,2,3,4,5]);

console.log(
  take(3) (ix));
  
console.log(
  ix.next().value,
  ix.next().value,
  ix.next().next().value)
```

No global state anywhere. You can implement it for any iterable data type. `take` is generic, that is it works with iterators of any data type.

Can anyone please explain me why native iterators are stateful? Why do the language designer hate functional programming?